# Cannot edit view filter with nested groups, value selector is out of view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Has anyone ever seen this UI design flaw ? I tried with IE11, latest Chrome, no go. When I get that level of nested criteria groups, values disappear.

I've also tried changing my screen resolution. No go. The screenshot is in french, but you get the idea. I specified where I'm expecting value selectors to show... ('Est égal à' means, 'Equals to')

Any ideas ? Is there a 3rd party tool for XrmToolBox that allows editing of views that wouldn't have this UI bug ?
[image]

Comment: Don't have access to a 2013 environment right now. Why don't you programmatically create the view with the desired fetchxml and see how CRM reacts? Could just be a client side UI issue while nesting groupings.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM That's what I'm thinking. The view works OK now because I put in the values before I did the grouping thing. But if I want to add something else, I think I'll have to ungroup, set the values, regroup. Or, like you said, create them through the API.